# How to parse filenames to determine the newest file in each of multiple folders

Tags: powershell

I have logs that are getting written from various Linux servers to a central windows NAS server. They're in E:\log in the format:

E:\log\process1\log20140901.txt,

E:\log\process2\20140901.txt,

E:\log\process3\log-process-20140901.txt,

etc.

Multiple files get copied on a weekly basis at the same time, so created date isn't a good way to determine what the newest file is. Therefore I wrote a powershell function to parse the date out, and I'm attempting to iterate through and get the newest file in each folder, using the output of my function as the "date". I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Here's the Powershell I've written so far:

```
Function ReturnDate ($file)
{
    $f = $file
    $f = [RegEx]::Matches($f,"(\d{8})") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
    $sqlDate = $f.Substring(0,4) + "-" + $f.substring(4,2) + "-" + $f.substring(6,2)
    return $sqlDate
}

Get-ChildItem E:\log\* |
 Where {$_.PsIsContainer} |
  foreach-object { Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse |
   Where {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
    ForEach-Object { ReturnDate $_}|
     Sort-Object ReturnDate -Descending |
      Select-Object -First 1 | Select Name,ReturnDate
       }
```

I seem to be confounding properties and causing "You cannot call a method on null-valued expression errors", but I'm uncertain what to do from here.

Comment: Where does the error occur in your code. Where you are running this     `ForEach-Object { ReturnDate $_}|Sort-Object ReturnDate -Descending` does this sort actually work? Your function would just return an object with a parameter called `ReturnDate`

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. Is there a way to assign "ReturnDate" as a parameter? Using LastWriteTime gives me files up to several weeks old, so I really want to integrate my name parsing function to determine the date.

Comment: You could create a custom object so that the rest of your coding work. I will make an answer. You current code returns empty string for the reason i mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your `$f` variable is null and you're trying to invoke a method (Substring) on a null value. Try this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Log -File -Recurse | Where Name -Match '(\d{8})\.' | 
    Foreach {Add-Member -Inp $_ NoteProperty ReturnDate ($matches[1]) -PassThru} | 
    Group DirectoryName | 
    Foreach {$_.Group | Sort ReturnDate -Desc | Select -First 1}
```

This does require V3 or higher.  If you're on V1 or V2 change it to this:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Log -Recurse | 
    Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -Match '(\d{8})\.'} | 
    Foreach {Add-Member -Inp $_ NoteProperty ReturnDate ($matches[1]) -PassThru} |
    Group DirectoryName | 
    Foreach {$_.Group | Sort ReturnDate -Desc | Select -First 1}
```

Comment: These are both giving me "Cannot index into a null array" errors.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you running?  I did test the first one on my machine running V4.

Comment: Major = 4, Minor = 0, Build = -1, Revision = -1

Comment: Hmm, I just tested the last one and it works as well.  The only place where an array is accessed is $matches[1].  That will only work if you specify a capture group in the regex i.e. the parens in `'(\d{8})\.'` are required.

Comment: Ah, now I'm seeing it.  Had to fire up a new console.  Apparently $matches wants to be accessed inside a scriptblock.  Try the first one again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was ok for me when i tried it up until you did a `select` you were requesting name and returndate when those properties did not exist. Creating a custom object with those values would make your code work. Also i removed some of the logic from your pipes. End result should still work though (I just made some dummy files to test with like your examples).

Working with your original code you could have something like this. This would only work on v3 or higher. Simple changes could make it work on lower if need be. Mostly where `[pscustomobject]` is concerned.

```
Function ReturnDate ($file)
{

    $f = $file
    $f = [RegEx]::Matches($f,"(\d{8})") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
    $sqlDate = $f.Substring(0,4) + "-" + $f.substring(4,2) + "-" + $f.substring(6,2)
    [pscustomobject] @{
        'Name' = $file.FullName
        'ReturnDate' = $sqlDate
    }
}

Get-ChildItem C:\temp\E\* -Recurse |
   Where-Object {!$_PSIsContainer} | 
   ForEach-Object{ReturnDate $_} |
   Sort-Object ReturnDate -Descending |
   Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: I'm getting "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression error using that. PS 4.0

Comment: Sorry about that. It did work for me. Did you change the `Get-ChildItem C:\temp\E\*` path to your own I am assuming.

Answer (score 1):

The `Sort-Object` cmdlet supports sorting by a custom script block and will sort by whatever the script block returns. So, use a regular expression to grab the timestamp and return it.

```
Get-ChildItem E:\log\* -Directory |
    ForEach-Object { 
        Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -File |
        Sort-Object -Property {
            if( $_.Name -match '(\d{8})' )
            {
                return $Matches[1]
            }
            Write-Error ('File ''{0}'' doesn't contain a timestamp in its name.' -f $_.FullName)
        } | 
        Select-Object -Last 1 | 
        Select Name,ReturnDate
    }
```

Note that `Select-Object -First 1` was changed to `Select-Object -Last 1`, since dates would be sorted from oldest to newest.